# Using the Django API

Tags: django, json, api, rest

First of all, any help with this would be amazing! I am currently trying to learn Django and am also fairly new to Python. I am trying to create a simple project management web service that could communicate using JSON with another application. All it needs to do is:

1. Give a list of all projects.
2. Give a list of all tasks for each of the projects.
3. Allow users to submit time for a project and task.

For models I currently have a 'Project' model and 'Task' model. I have filled the database with some dummy information. My project model has variables id, name, and description. Task just has project, task_name.

My view for task 1 above is

```
def api(request):
projects = Project.objects.all()#.order_by('id')
projects = serializers.serialize('json', projects, indent=2)
return HttpResponse(projects, mimetype='application/json')
```

associated url is    url(r'^api/project/$', 'project.views.api'),

However this outputs the text below when typing

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project/
```

into the browser. Is there a better way to test JSON output? I would rather it only output the 'id' and 'name'. For some reason the id doesn't even show. This is what I put for id in models id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True). It works in the interactive shell.

```
[
  {
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "project.project", 
    "fields": {
      "name": "Project One", 
      "description": "This is the description for project one"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "pk": 2, 
    "model": "project.project", 
    "fields": {
      "name": "Project Two", 
      "description": "This is Project Two"
    }
  }
]
```

I learn by example so if someone could show me how this should be done I would be extremely grateful!

By the way for outputting the list of tasks, I was thinking the url would be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project/?project_name
```

but I'm not sure how to handle that in the view.

Comment: Or rather pk is an alias for id, and you don't need to actually define `id` on your model: Django creates that automatically.

Comment: instead of Projects.objects.all() what can I use to only spit out the id and name... without "model" and "description" ?

Comment: You mean a [subset of fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields)?

Comment: you can use dehydrate to get restricted/additional list of field - http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id2